# Android Gradle : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError for one of my classes that i am accessing in the Application sub class. Strangely it only occurs if i add a certain dependency to the project (zendesk) otherwise it works fine. FYI zendesk is dependent on picasso and support libraries that i am also using in my project. So, my dependencies look like this before adding zendesk:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
        ..
        ..
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
  }
```

but if i add zendesk to the dependencies list

```
compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.0.1')
```

i get a NoClassDefFoundError for a class being referenced from the application sub class. And i am not even using zendesk sdk anywhere in the code for now.

Comment: Can you post the output of the "gradlew -q dependencies" command?  This will show all the dependent libraries. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AndroidGuy I actually had the multidex support improperly enabled. Fixing that fixed the problem. Not sure why ?